# How to fix No Module named Kivy? Have already tried PATH method from other thread and installing Kivy multiple different ways

Tags: python, kivy

So I wrote out this code:

```
from kivy.uix.label import Label 

class myApp(app):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello World')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myApp().run()
```

but I get this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\azuge\Documents\code\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from kivy.app import App
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'
```

Tried the PATH method on the original thread for this question but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

What operating system are you using? If you're using Windows 10, you can try `pip install kivy` using the command prompt. If that doesn't work, have you followed the steps in [the documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html#install-pip)?